# prestashop - how can I get a cms page title in a .tpl?

Tags: title, prestashop

I was wandering if there was a faster way to get a cms title in a .tpl

For now, I extended the Tools class with a really simple method:

```
public static function getCMSTitle($id_cms,$id_lang){
    $cms = new CMS($id_cms, $id_lang);
    return $cms->meta_title;
}
```

So that I can then do this:

```
<li><a href="{$link->getCMSLink(1)}">{Tools::getCMSTitle(1,$cookie->id_lang)}</a></li>
```

I think it's important because, if you simply do {l s="pagename"} you then must translate the page name twice.

So, fine. But since it's really simple, I can't believe that there's no way to do it via smarty. It's not good to extend the Tools class only to do that simple task..

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried {$meta_title|escape:'html':'UTF-8'} directly on the tpl? I've just tested on cms.tpl and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Simple as pie without any overrides (PS 1.6.1.14)

**{$cms->meta_title}** to get CMS page title

**{$cms->meta_description}** to get description

and many other content based on columns name in **ps_cms_lang** table.

Answer (score 0):

If you are like me, I understand you want to access to the page title OUTSIDE of the page.
If so, previous answers didn't help.

In this page, I have found a solution to this: https://toniravsadhu.wordpress.com/2014/02/27/prestashop-how-can-i-get-a-cms-page-title-in-a-tpltemplate-file/

First: Extend the Tools class adding the following method

```
public static function getCMSTitle($id_cms,$id_lang){
  $cms = new CMS($id_cms, $id_lang);
  return $cms->meta_title;
}
```

Then, in the template you can now use the following to get the title from a CMS page ID:

```
<a>{Tools::getCMSTitle(1,$cookie->id_lang)}</a>
```